# Extracting numbers with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, zsh

Input

```
...
...
PANO_20190917_185957.jpg
BURST20201216180114905_COVER.jpg
BURST20201214164624071_COVER.jpg
IMG_20190317_112951.jpg
IMG_20190317_112939.jpg
IMG_20190317_112936.jpg
IMG_20190317_112947.jpg
IMG_20200326_013746.jpg
...
...
```

Sed

```
$ fd . ./ -t f | sed  -E 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,6\}\).*/\1/'  
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Desired Output

```
...
...
201909
202012
202012
201903
201903
201903
201903
202003
...
...
```

Any other way to do this? I've been struggling all day trying to get this working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]{1,6}).*/\1/' file

201909
202012
202012
201903
201903
201903
201903
202003
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `-E`: Enable extender regex mode (ERE)
- `^`: Start
- `[^0-9]*`: Match 0 or more non-digits
- `([0-9]{1,6})`: Match 1 to 6 digits in 1st capture group
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your command:

1. `-E` makes `sed` treat your regex as a POSIX ERE but the syntax it complies with is that of POSIX BRE,
2. You match any text with `.*` that grabs all text greedily, and the next digit matching pattern always matches just a single digit since it can match a single digit,
3. you want exactly 6 digits in the output, but you allow 1 to 6.

You can use the following POSIX BRE solution:

```sh
sed  -n 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{6\}\).*/\1/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FKWFWy) where

- `-n` suppresses the default line output
- `[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{6\}\).*` matches zero or more chars other than digits, then captured exactly 6 digits into Group 1, and then matches the rest of the string, and
- `\1` - replaces the whole match with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.